# Django Heroku users_customuser table can't migrate

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-custom-user

I have a Django project I've been developing locally for a while. It works fine on my local machine, and I am using a customuser setup so that my login auth only needs email / password, as opposed to the default Django user table which needs email / username / password.

I just got my project hosted on Heroku, and can see the webpage UI get loaded fine. But I'm getting Django errors when clicking any links, and think its connected to an issue when I try to run

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

I'm trying to run this on heroku to setup the DB, but when I do so I get an error saying:

```
Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ songsweeper... up, run.1353 (Free)
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, contenttypes, playlist, sessions, sites
Running migrations:
  Applying account.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "users_customuser" does not exist


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 234, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 247, in apply_migration
    migration_recorded = True
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 110, in __exit__
    self.execute(sql)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 137, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "users_customuser" does not exist
```

My project is very large, but to give an overview of where I'm defining customuser, it appears in these places:

[image]

Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this migration error? Or is it indicative or something alrger? The 'sign-in' link on my site leads to a different error saying "relation "django_site" does not exist", but I think it has something to do with this failed customuser error.

I am currently using the default sqlite3 db.

Comment: I'm guessing that there is something wrong with your migration files. As a quick fix, I would suggest deleting all migration files of all apps and running `makemigration` and `migrate` on the `heroku` server.

Comment: yes thank you that appeared to be the problem, i was deleting stuff in ym git repo and commititn got the heorku server but it wasnt getting added. had to go in via bash and manually delete the migrations, as well as migrate the user app specifically. wroks now thx

Answer (score 1):

I faced the problem similar to yours before.
In my opinion, I think it is because of a migration file in the user app.
So you will have to do migrate the user model.

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations users
$ python manage.py migrate
```

I resolved the problem using the above way.